# build.gradle: How to convert Groovy-ish custom task to Kotlin-ish?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have such custom task written via Groovy:

```
task systemTest(type: Test, description: 'Runs the system tests', group: 'Verification'){
    exclude "**/**Smoke.class"
    exclude "**/**Test.class"
    exclude "**/**IT.class"
    include "**/**ST.class"

    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        showStandardStreams = true
        showCauses true
        showExceptions true
        showStackTraces true
    }
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
        if (!desc.parent) {
            def output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
            def startItem = '|  ', endItem = '  |'
            def repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
            println('\n\n\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + "\n$startItem $output $endItem\n" + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n\n\n')
        }
    }
    systemTest.finalizedBy('allureReport')
}
```

Tried to convert this snippet via tools, e.g. [this one](https://gradle-kotlinize.web.app/) or [this one](https://github.com/bernaferrari/GradleKotlinConverter)
and then refactor script manually:

```kotlin
val systemTest by tasks.registering(Test::class) {
    description = "Runs the system tests"
    group = "Verification"

    exclude("**/**Smoke.class")
    exclude("**/**Test.class")
    exclude("**/**IT.class")
    include("**/**ST.class")

    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = "full"
        events = setOf("passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError")
        showStandardStreams = true
        showCauses = true
        showExceptions = true
        showStackTraces = true
    }
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
        if (!desc.parent) {
            val output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
            val startItem = "|  "
            val endItem = "  |"
            val repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
            println("\n\n\n" + ("-" * repeatLength) + "\n$startItem $output $endItem\n" + ("-" * repeatLength) + "\n\n\n")
        }
    }
    systemTest.finalizedBy("allureReport")
}
```

but nevertheless got a lot of errors on `./gradlew systemTest`:

```
* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 44:         exceptionFormat = "full"
                                     ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is String but TestExceptionFormat! was expected

  Line 45:         events = setOf("passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError")
                            ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is String but TestLogEvent! was expected

  Line 45:         events = setOf("passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError")
                            ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is Set<String> but (Mutable)Set<TestLogEvent!>! was expected

  Line 51:     afterSuite { desc, result ->
                          ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is ([ERROR : <Unknown lambda parameter type>], [ERROR : <Unknown lambda parameter type>]) -> Unit but Closure<(raw) Any!>! was expected

  Line 51:     afterSuite { desc, result ->
                            ^ Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

  Line 51:     afterSuite { desc, result ->
                                  ^ Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

  Line 56:             val repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                                                    ^ Expression 'length' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

  Line 56:             val repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                                                                      ^ Expression 'length' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

  Line 56:             val repeatLength = startItem.length() + output.length() + endItem.length()
                                                                                         ^ Expression 'length' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

  Line 57:             println("\n\n\n" + ("-" * repeatLength) + "\n$startItem $output $endItem\n" + ("-" * repeatLength) + "\n\n\n")
                                               ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                                                   public inline operator fun BigDecimal.times(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
                                                   public inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

  Line 57:             println("\n\n\n" + ("-" * repeatLength) + "\n$startItem $output $endItem\n" + ("-" * repeatLength) + "\n\n\n")
                                                                                                          ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                                                                                                              public inline operator fun BigDecimal.times(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
                                                                                                              public inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

  Line 60:     systemTest.finalizedBy("allureReport")
               ^ Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly

12 errors
```

`java -version`:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

used plugins in build script:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.10"
    id("java")
    id("io.qameta.allure") version "2.11.2"
}
```

Any help in pointing out what am I doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ then it might best to first comment out all erroring lines, [sync and refresh](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle/syncing-and-reloading/) until IntelliJ picks up the config, and you'll have JavaDoc, auto-complete, and in-line errors and hints.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```kotlin
  val systemTest by tasks.registering(Test::class) {
    description = "Runs the system tests"
    group = "Verification"

    exclude("**/**Smoke.class")
    exclude("**/**Test.class")
    exclude("**/**IT.class")
    include("**/**ST.class")

    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
      exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
      events = setOf(TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.FAILED, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR)
      showStandardStreams = true
      showCauses = true
      showExceptions = true
      showStackTraces = true
    }
    afterSuite(KotlinClosure2<TestDescriptor, TestResult, Any>({ desc, result ->
      if (desc.parent == null) {
        val output = "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
        val startItem = "|  "
        val endItem = "  |"
        val repeatLength = startItem.length + output.length + endItem.length
        println("\n\n\n" + ("-".repeat(repeatLength)) + "\n$startItem $output $endItem\n" + ("-".repeat(repeatLength)) + "\n\n\n")
      }
    }))
    finalizedBy(tasks.named("allureReport"))
  }
```

I've been converting to `gradle.kts` too. What helped was starting the `build.gradle.kts` file again, seems IntelliJ doesn't give syntax highlighting until it has synced on a valid file (even if it's empty). Also searching GitHub is how I figured out bits such as [`afterSuite`](https://github.com/search?q=aftersuite++path%3A**%2Fbuild.gradle.kts&type=code&ref=advsearch).